What would be an appropriate translation of Solitude?
I am looking for a fitting translation of solitude. The results I found online do not seem appropriate:

Einsamkeit - Often translated into loneliness - seems to be more focused on the negative aspects due to a lock of social interaction.
Alleinsein - Seems like an objective about someone being alone.
Abgeschiedenheit - Seems like it is used to describe someone or something which is not near others.

In my understanding solitude has some kind of intention behind which the stated translations do not caputre.

Einsamkeit and Alleinsein are usually describing a (half)-conscious state of persons, whereas Abgeschiedenheit is most often referring to a geographic place that is no reached easily by standard means of transportation and not frequented by many people. The alpine literature often says "In der Abgeschiedenheit der .... Berge" (in the remote mountains...). Someone spending time in a monastery is "in der Abgeschiedenheit des Klosters" (separated from businesses of everyday life).

One term not mentioned is

Zurückgezogenheit (seclusion), see
DWDS

which at the least covers the intention of  the affected person. Insisting on a one-word translation will often fail, however, so different means may become necessary.

Selbstgewählte Einsamkeit

is a good alternative.

Intentional solitude is often called die Klausur. That's what monks do when they live alone for a few days, and it's also used when someone does that for doing some work alone.

Ich gehe dann mal in Klausur.

It's more common not to use a noun though.

Ich ziehe mich dann mal für eine Weile zurück.


Good answer. It might be worth mentioning that Klausur can also refer to a group which is intentionally isolating itself for a certain period of time.

One possible word is "das Alleinsein" which literally translates to be with oneself (or as group or couple being separated from all other social contacts to external people).
Practically I'd probably choose a different approach and would not translate literally, but to something like "Zeit für mich / sich / uns / Euch selbst" (time for myself / onself / ourselves / yourselves"
The "Zurückgezogenheit" or "selbstgewählte Einsamkeit" as mentioned by guidot might also be valid translations.
Which translation is favourable would strongly depend on context and the intended connotations. This is (to me) a clear example how the choice of language can influence the way of thinking due to quite different connotations of the words involved.
